# Coturn server incomplete logs

Tags: kurento, coturn, rfc5766turnserver

I have a Corturn server installed and working fine for most of the scenarios. However there are some error scenarios which I need to investigate through logs. However it doesnt print any logs in log file after startup logs. Your suggestions really appreciated. Below are all the logs I got in my log file.

```
0: log file opened: /var/log/turn_2018-04-27.log
0: pid file created: /var/run/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0:   relay 10.10.1.121 initialization...
0:   relay 10.10.1.121 initialization done
0:   relay ::1 initialization...
0:   relay ::1 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=0 created
0: turn server id=1 created
0: turn server id=2 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=3 created
0: Total General servers: 4
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (admin thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: SQLite DB connection success: /var/lib/turn/turndb
```